# How to pivot given string by replacing special characters in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

In an interview, I have been asked to pivot a string by replacing special characters.

Given string was `'AAA%BBB$CCC#DDD'`

Expected output as shown in then image:

[image: Expected Output]

How can we do this in SQL Server? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you define `special characters` and do you need the position of each substring? If you use SQL Server 2017+, a combination of `TRANSLATE()` and `STRING_SPLIT()` is a possible option.

Comment: @Zhorov How can we do this in SQL Server 2014?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2014?(I guess the operating system you are using is Windows Server 2008 R2, hahaha),
if you use SQL Server 2014-, basically, you need to unify the different separators first,

```
declare @str as varchar(1024) = 'AAA%BBB$CCC#DDD'
set @str = REPLACE(@str, '%', ',')
set @str = REPLACE(@str, '$', ',')
set @str = REPLACE(@str, '#', ',')
```

then like this:

```
;with c0 as
(
select REPLACE(@str, '"', '') + ',' as col0
), c1 as
(
select LEFT(col0, CHARINDEX(',', col0) - 1) as col1,
       STUFF(col0, 1, CHARINDEX(',', col0), '') as col2
from c0
union all
select LEFT(col2, CHARINDEX(',', col2) - 1) as col1,
       STUFF(col2, 1, CHARINDEX(',', col2), '') as col2
from c1
where LEN(col2) > 0
)

select col1 from c1 where col1 <> 'null'
```

OR

```
;with c0 as
(
select @str as s
), c1 as
(
select number as n from master.dbo.spt_values where type = 'P'
)
select SUBSTRING(c0.s, c1.n, CHARINDEX(',', c0.s+',', c1.n)-c1.n) as item,
       c1.n - LEN(REPLACE(LEFT(c0.s, c1.n), ',', '')) + 1 as pos1,
       ROW_NUMBER() over(order by c1.n) as pos2,
       c1.n, c0.s
from c0
inner join c1 on c1.n <= LEN(c0.s) and SUBSTRING(','+c0.s, c1.n, 1) = ','
```

OR

```
set @str = 'select col1 = ''' + REPLACE(@str,',',''' union all select ''') + ''''
set @str = 'select col1 from (' + @str + ') as D'
exec(@str)
```

OR

```
set @str = '(values (''' + REPLACE(@str,',',''' ),( ''') + ''')) as tb(item)'
set @str = 'select item from ' + @str
exec(@str)
```